# Is it possible to block ONLY the homepage of YouTube but not its videos using /etc/hosts?

Tags: youtube, hosts

**Use Case: Block the homepage of YouTube (https://www.youtube.com) but not YouTube videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1lsbF9NWW0)**

In order to block the YouTube homepage, I modified my `/etc/hosts` file with the following content:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       user-pc
127.0.1.1       www.youtube.com
```

However, adding `127.0.1.1 www.youtube.com` will disallow users from browsing the YouTube homepage along with anything else that starts with `www.youtube.com`.

Then how can I possibly modify this file so that it is only the homepage that will blocked and not the videos?